# Read image from gallery getting a Runtime exception. Image size is more than 1MB of data. How to fix this issue using java in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-edittext

**Perform Gallery Action **

As mentioned in below lines of code to perform action to read images from the Gallery.

```
    Intent intent = null;
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Getting Runtime exception :

```
Uncaught exception: Error Message: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1132804 bytes
at android.app.ActivityClient.activityStopped(ActivityClient.java:86)
at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:143)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1132804 bytes
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:635)
at android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityClientController.java:1358)
at android.app.ActivityClient.activityStopped(ActivityClient.java:83)
... 9 more

Comment: `lines of code to perform action to read images from the Gallery.` ? Those lines of code do not read an image. They let the user select an image. Thats all.

Comment: After Performing above lines of code app get runtime exception.

Comment: Even before the user selected an image file? Please explain better what happens. Complete scenario.

Comment: Created one sample application. To read image from the Gallery. 
After selecting image from gallery i got runtime exception.  
Please check above lines for the runtime exception.

Comment: The code you posted is for before selection. The error you posted is of after image selection. Post the code that is invoked after image selection. The code that produces the error.  There were you try to read the image. Probably in or after onActivityResult.

Comment: If you have no question about `java` language, `android-studio`, `android-fragments` and `android-edittext` then please remove those tags.

Comment: This is Completly related to Android app issue. I think your suggesrion not related to above issue. 

Tags are correct as per the above issue.
Android-studio - Tag For app developement
Android-fragments - taG we used fragment to read image from gallery 
Android-editext tag - Tag we used for entering some other info
I mention all tags for more review comments on this issue.